# debug SES email receiving issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-ses

I'm using AWS SES to receive emails and upload email objects to s3 storage. Last week I could not receive emails for an interval of almost 5 hours.

[image]

How do I debug what happened? I don't know where to find logs of any kind for this.

Comment: There should be some logging from AWS SES. Have you checked the logs ?

Comment: there's no way to check email receiving.

Comment: You can get logs for the failure from SES, right ?

Comment: no. that;s the problem with "email receiving". only this metric is there in terms of visibiity for "email receiving" https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/receiving-email-metrics.html, which is also pretty new feature. just to be sure you are not confused with "email sending", on which there will be lots of customization ,control and visibility.